# Passing value from Controller to View in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, view, controller

I have a view that was generated using data scaffolding. The view has a textfield:

**Create View:**

```
     <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GroupId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.GroupId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GroupId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'd like to pass a value from a controller to this textfield. And I did the following, which doesn't seem to work.

**Controller:**

```
    public ActionResult Create(int id)
    {
        ViewBag.GroupId = id;
        Debug.WriteLine("DEBUG: "+id);
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: your `ViewBag` is not your `model`, you can't just interchange them.  If you check your `ViewBag.GroupId` in your view, you'll get the value.  If you need a model, you should pass that into your view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this by using the `ViewBag` to store `GroupId` as you currently are, but as your view is using a model, it may be better to go that way instead.

So you would have:

**Model:**

```
public class GroupModel
{
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Create(int id)
{
    var model = new GroupModel();
    model.GroupId = id

    return View(model);
}
```

At the top of your view, you would then reference your model:

```
@model GroupModel
```

You can then access the model in the view using code like `model.GroupId` as per the scaffolding has done.

Answer (score 0):

One additional thing to point out is that if you are passing a key value that is stored in the web.config file, say for reCAPTCHA, and the validation fails then you will need to also set the key value in the HttpPost section.